# How to exclude tax from price in magento 1.9?

Tags: php, magento, checkout, onepage-checkout

i have magento 1.9

here tax is assumed as 5%

i have two types products some includes the tax in its price and some not include the tax in price.

now i want the subtotal like this

```
product price ==> 1995

subtotal ==> 1895

tax ==> 100

grand total ==> 1995
```

for excluding tax products and

for non-excluding tax products i want subtotal like this.

```
product price ==> 1995

subtotal ==> 1995

tax ==> 100

grand total ==> 2095
```

Answer (score 2):

In magento There is option in Tax setting to Manage subtotal and grand total for Tax. I am not sure if you are looking for same or not. I can't add image in comment so i add answer. Hope it will help.[image]

See below another setting for cross price check.

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, i have tried this but the problem is that it adds the tax again to the products which already has tax in its price.

Comment: @iharshdesai Please check I have update answer. May be this will help you.